# Convert string to list using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to convert string like below to list using Python.

```
sample_str = '["sample text1", "\'sample text2\'", "sample text3"]'
```

If we check the data type of "sample_str" above, it will be string. I need to know if there a way I could make it a list like below :

```
sample_str_to_list = ["sample text1", "\'sample text2\'", "sample text3"]
```

If we check the data type of "sample_str_to_list" above, it will be list.

I have tried to do it using string slicing, but it did not help. Can somebody please help here.
Thank in advance.

Comment: Check [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) for a safer version than `eval`.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have a JSON value to decode? I would be surprised if you actually want to keep the  backslashes, which aren't part of the original string, only part of the string-literal syntax to allow a single quote to be included in the literal.

Comment: You could do `sample_str[1:-1].split(',')` and take the extra quotes off, but getting what you need directly might be better - where does the original string come from?

Comment: Alternatively, you can take the long route by `.replace()` all the unwanted characters then converting it to a list i guess

Comment: `json.loads('["sample text1", "\'sample text2\'", "sample text3"]')` and/or `ast.literal_eval('["sample text1", "\'sample text2\'", "sample text3"]')` both should work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have looks an awful lot like JSON:

```
>>> sample_str = '["sample text1", "\'sample text2\'", "sample text3"]'
>>> import json
>>> json.loads(sample_str)
['sample text1', "'sample text2'", 'sample text3']
```

If it's actually the representation of a Python `str` value, there's `ast.literal_eval`:

```
>>> import ast
>>> ast.literal_eval(sample_str)
['sample text1', "'sample text2'", 'sample text3']
```

If it's neither of the above, you're going to have to identify the encoding scheme and find a parser for it, or write your own.

Answer (score 0):

you could use `ast.list_eval`, for a safer `eval`

```
from ast import literal_eval
sample_str = '["sample text1", "\'sample text2\'", "sample text3"]'
sample_str = literal_eval(sample_str)
```

Output:

```
['sample text1', "'sample text2'", 'sample text3']
```

Answer (score -2):

You can try using [exec](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/functions.html?highlight=exec#exec)

```
exec("""
sample_str_to_list = ["sample text1", "'sample text2'", "sample text3"]
""")
```

Comment: oh, if not `eval` then `exec`, why?

Comment: Do not use neither [`eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) nor [`exec()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec), the only appropriate way to evaluate code is [`ast.literal_eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval). **BUT** better to avoid this at all and solve task using string parsing.